# Get paths within a specific subset of directories at the same level using glob

Tags: python, glob

Using `glob.glob` in Python, I would like to get paths from only some directories existing in the same level, while skipping but not others e.g. If A, B, and C, D, F ... X. are directories at the same level, I want to get paths A and B, while skipping all the others C, D, F ..., X. The directory names are arbitrarily long i.e. one or more characters as names.

```py
import glob

glob.glob('A/*') # get all paths linked to A
glob.glob('B/*') # get all paths linked to B
glob.glob('*/*') # get all paths linked to A, B, but also C, D, E, F, ... , X. This is not the solution.
```

In bash one can do `ls {A,B}/*`, to skip all the other directories. I wonder if an equivalent for `glob.glob` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glob already supports regex. You can refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) documentation.

To get the others except "c" in your example in your example, you can use like this:

```
glob.glob("[!c]/*")
```

Or just to get what passes a or b:

```
glob.glob("[a,b]/*")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to edit the question a bit, to indicate there could be more directories e.g. (D, E, F ... Z), and this specific regex will also go through them. The solution query needs to focus only on A and B to work.

Comment: I updated my answer to fit the new question

Comment: Thanks. This is near a solution. I wonder if this particular pattern can be also adapted to directory names with an arbitrary number of characters e.g. replacing "A" with "foo" will keep extracting files from "B', but not from "foo".

Comment: Glob has a very superficial regex and I don't think you can figure it out. As a longer but effective way you could try:  sum([glob.glob(f"{i}/*") for i in os.listdir(".") if re.match(r'(a|foo)',i)], [])